# MySQL - Nested Foreign Keys (with multiple tables)

Tags: mysql, database, join, foreign-keys

I have table bus and routes, and table fare_t has bus and routes' primary key as foreign key. And another table time_t has fare_t's primary key as foreign key.
Now I want to make a query and join them together in such a way that the query returns data from table time_t containing data from table fare_t along with the data from table bus and routes of which's primary key is added as foreign key in table fare_t.

How to write the query??

I've tried the following,

```
SELECT bus.name, routes.route_from, routes.route_to, fare_t.fare, time_t.time FROM time_t 
INNER JOIN bus ON bus.id = fare_t.bus_id
INNER JOIN routes ON routes.id  = fare_t.route_id
INNER JOIN fare_t ON fare_t.id = time_t.fare_t_t;
```

It produces the following error `#1054 - Unknown column 'fare_t.bus_id' in 'on clause'`

Comment: Remove the `sql-server`tag if your question is about MySQL.

Comment: okay, it suggested so I added it mistakenly

Comment: I removed it for you & also answered your question

Comment: Thank you, checking your answer @Gab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using `fare_t` table before joining it, try:

```
SELECT bus.name, routes.route_from, routes.route_to, fare_t.fare, time_t.time
FROM time_t 
JOIN fare_t ON fare_t.id = time_t.fare_t_t
JOIN bus ON bus.id = fare_t.bus_id
JOIN routes ON routes.id  = fare_t.route_id;
```

If it does not work, please share the schema of `fare_t`.

**Update:**

For demonstration purpose, here is the same exact bug reproduced with a different schema:

```
mysql> SELECT *
    -> FROM users u
    -> JOIN user_skill uss ON uss.active = us.active
    -> JOIN user_state us ON us.uid = u.id;
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'us.active' in 'on clause'
mysql> 
mysql> SELECT *
    -> FROM users u
    -> JOIN user_state us ON us.uid = u.id
    -> JOIN user_skill uss ON uss.active = us.active
    -> ;
Empty set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! It's working as expected now :D